# Rails - jqGrid cannot sort and search using will_paginate/array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jqgrid, will-paginate

I use jqGrid and will_paginate to make a table.
Here's my code in the controller

```
def index
  index_columns ||= [:pid,:name,:gender,:birthday,:school]
  current_page = params[:page] ? params[:page].to_i : 1
  rows_per_page = params[:rows] ? params[:rows].to_i : 10

  conditions={:page => current_page, :per_page => rows_per_page}
  conditions[:order] = params["sidx"] + " " + params["sord"] unless (params[:sidx].blank? || params[:sord].blank?)

  if params[:_search] == "true"
    conditions[:conditions]=filter_by_conditions(index_columns)
  end

  @people = Person.paginate(conditions)
  total_entries=@people.total_entries

  respond_with(@people) do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @people.to_jqgrid_json(index_columns, current_page, rows_per_page, total_entries)}  
  end
end
```

With these code, the data can be sort and search correctly in jqGrid.
However, after I modifying it to

```
  @temp = Person.limit(0).all
  KlassesPeople.where(:klass_id => 1).each do |stu|
    @temp.concat( Person.where(:id => stu.person_id) )
  end

  @people = @temp.paginate(conditions)
  total_entries=@people.total_entries
```

The data still can be shown in jqGrid but can't be sort and search
I do add require 'will_paginate/array' in my controller

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded jqgrid server side search and CRUD operation using ruby on rails 4.0

find the below link -

https://github.com/Rameshwar007/jqgrid_rails_4_sample

Let me know If you any further query.